# Which is best way to merge more commits into one commit

Tags: git

I have new feature branch named "new_feature". I create 2 commits named:

```
"testing"
```

and

```
"testing2"
```

I push this commits to git, project leader checkout my branch and he is satisfied.
After this I fix just one more small fix with commit "small_fix", so now I have three commits:

```
"testing"
"testing2"
"small fix"
```

But I want merge all this in one commit named "new_feature_all_done".
I deleted remote branch named "new_feature", now I need to merge this 3 commits in one commit(new_feature_all_done) and push branch "new_feature" to remote but this time with one commit(new_feature_all_done). Which is best way to do this ?

I can copy my working folder somewere on disc, delete local branch "new_feature", create branch "new_feature" again and then paste working directory from disc to git working folder and then commit and push changes, but this in dirty way and I want more elegant way...

Answer (score 1):

Try interactive git rebase:

```
git rebase -i BRANCH_NAME~3
```

Here

- `BRANCH_NAME` - name of your local branch
- `3` - number of commits in your branch to be rebased.

Comment: rebase is not good way because if I have 10 commits and I need merge this 10 commits into one rebase process take lot of time, I want elegant and fast way to put current state to one commit.